# Create an array with properties using ._range()

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to create an array that has id and value properties by using `_.range()`.

```
var ohYeah = function() {
  var jawn = _.range(4);
  console.log(jawn);
};
ohYeah();

jawn exports 
[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
```

and I want an array that looks like

```
[{id: 1, value: '1'}, {id: 2, value: '2'}, {id: 3, value: '3'}...]
```

Is this possible with lodash? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://lodash.com/docs#range

`_.range` returns an array of integers, and you want an array of objects.  An easy solution is to map those integers to objects that look like your desired output.

As an aside, to get the range you want (from 1 to 4), you can either do `_.range(1, 5)`, or add 1 to each array element.  I've chosen the latter:

```
var ohYeah = function() {
  var jawn = _.map(_.range(4), function(x) {
    return {
      id: x + 1,
      value: '' + (x + 1)
    };
  });
  console.log(jawn);
};
ohYeah();
```